# How can I code division and remainder predicates in prolog without using the build-in aithmetic

Tags: prolog, division

I need to write a division and a remainder predicates (yes two predicates) in Prolog without using the build-in arithmetic. It needs to be new predicates: division(X,Y,Z) meaning integer result of X divided by Y is Z. And remainder(X,Y,Z) meaning the remainder of X divided by Y is Z.

Yes, I need to code them from scratch. I'm not allowed to use the build-in arithmetic.

How can I do that? Could you give me the examples and explain it to me why it works?

Comment: Without %, +, - and * it seems a little bit difficult

Comment: Yes, I know. I can't deal with this by myself, but thinking about it for a long time.

Comment: Hi Olga. Didn't you ask that question already twice? What has changed? Is this still Peano Arithmetic or something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Times, Quotient and Remainder predicates in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132704/times-quotient-and-remainder-predicates-in-prolog)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a complete solution but you could build on it to grow it further...
I am representing integer numbers as a list full of i.
so [i,i,i,i] == 4

I have not written you a conversion of the results to integers but you will need to define the 10 digits and work your way to from there to form multi digit numbers.

I do not support zero division... And have not really debugged this thing... I just got it as an idea and wrote it down :-D

Perhaps you can start it to build something cool out of it!

```
div(X, Y, Z, R) :-
    div_inner(X, Y, Y, Z, R).

div_inner([], [], _, [i], []).
div_inner([], [i|Y], _, [], [i|Y]).
div_inner([i|X], [], D, [i|Z], R) :-
    div_inner([i|X], D, D, Z, R).
div_inner([i|X], [i|Y], D, Z, R):-
    div_inner(X, Y, D, Z, R).
```

it is only one predicate that returns you both values. Z is the result R is the remainder!

Clearly performance is not considered here just pure artistic coding :-D

Have fun

Answer (score -1):

Using DCGs:

```
compute_divrem(X, Y, Div, Rem):-
  Y\=0,
  length(LX, X), length(LY, Y),
  once(phrase(divrem(LY, LDiv), LX, LRem)),
  length(LDiv, Div), length(LRem, Rem).

divrem(X, [_|LDiv]) --> X, divrem(X, LDiv).
divrem(_, []) --> [].
```

Test case:

```
?- compute_divrem(100,7,Div,Rem).
Div = 14,
Rem = 2.
```